# Apply function to a list of lists

Tags: r, list, loops, apply, lapply

I have a list of length 100. Each entry is itself a list containing 31 matrices with 10 rows and five columns.

```
>length(dati_fault)
[1] 100
```

```
> length(dati_fault[[1]])
[1] 31
```

I should get 100 averages of the variables summarizing the 31 matrices each element of the list

```
media_1<-list()
for(i in nrow(dati_fault)){
  for(j in nrow(dati_fault[[i]]))
  media_1[[i]]<-lapply(dati_fault, colMeans(j))
  
}
media_1
```

But I get nothing because the media_1 list remains empty

Comment: what is your desired output? Do you simply want to compute the `colMeans` of each matrix?

Comment: You want to calculate the average per column of each item in the list.
So I have to calculate the average per variable of 31 matrices that correspond to the single element of the Maxi List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need `for`  loops to do so. You can directly work with `lapply`:

```
lapply(dati_fault, \(x) colMeans(do.call(rbind, x)))
```

This does the following: for each entry of `dati_fault` (i.e. each sublist of 31 matrices) these matrices are bound together (using `rbind`) into one single matrix with 310 rows and 5 columns. Then, `colMeans` is applied to this matrix.

If you are not familiar with the shorthand notation for anonymous functions (i.e. `\(x)`) you can read about it [here](https://www.jumpingrivers.com/blog/new-features-r410-pipe-anonymous-functions/).

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to achieve, I thought it would be much more complicated. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out right away. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

**sample data**

```
dati_fault <- lapply(1:100, function(x) {
  rep(list(matrix(sample(50, replace = T), nrow = 10, ncol = 5)), 31)
})
```

**case 1: calculate means for each matrix**

```
# to get the colMeans of each matrix (100 * 31 mean vectors)
lapply(dati_fault, function(x) lapply(x, colMeans))
```

**case 2: calculate the mean of all matrixes in same list**

```
# to get the colMeans of all 31 matrixes together (100 mean vectors) 
lapply(dati_fault, function(x) colMeans(do.call(rbind, x)))
```